# adding UIKit Dynamics to a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout. dynamicAnimator seems to use default layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uikit-dynamics

I am trying to add `UIDynamics` to a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

I want the `dynamicAnimator` to animate every cell when scrolling. They should behave in a more realistic manner and just like the iMessage bubbles do. They seem to react to the physical forces applied to them while scrolling. I want the `dynamicAnimator` to animate my cells in the same way. I know that the `dynamicAnimator` will change the cells’ centers a lot and very quickly to create the illusion of physical forces being applied to the cells. I found a tutorial explaining how to do this with a `UICollectionView` and `UIKit Dynamics` [tutorial with example project](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html). I do understand every step of this tutorial.

I uploaded an image to clarify what I want to achieve. See the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgvAK.png) (my reputation is not high enough to post images, yet). Following the tutorial will result in a layout that looks somewhat  like layout (2). This is very close to what I want. However, there is one thing I want to change: the cells’ centers on the collectionView. I want the cells’ initial centers to be as in layout (1) and not as in layout (2).

Before using the dynamicAnimator I set the cells’ centers in the `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`-method. However, I need to find a way to inform the dynamicAnimator that the cells’ centers are not as in layout (2) but in layout (1). Obviously, I do not know how to meld the information that comes from the layout and the information that comes from the animator.

Therefore, I will try to rephrase my question. How can I melt the information that comes from the layout and the information that comes from the animator?

To include some code: How can I make the example from the tutorial above look more like layout (2) (thus how can I change the cells’ initial centers)? Where do I tell the dynamicAnimator where the cells’ centers should be?

The project can be found at the beginning of the tutorial above and is called `ASHSpringyCollectionView` and that results in something like layout (2).

// **Below is the initial version of the question. I rewrote it for more clearity (everything above this  part is rewritten). I kept this old version of the question here for the sake of completeness.**

I am trying to add `UIDynamics` to a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I am using piemonte's custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`    PBJHexagon It creates a nice hexagon layout. However, in order to achieve this special layout, he changed the cells' center in the "`layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`"-method:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
NSInteger row = (NSInteger) CGFloat_nearbyint( CGFloat_floor(indexPath.row / _itemsPerRow) );
NSInteger col = indexPath.row % _itemsPerRow;

CGFloat horiOffset = ((row % 2) != 0) ? 0 : self.itemSize.width * 0.5f;
CGFloat vertOffset = 0;

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
attributes.size = self.itemSize;
attributes.center = CGPointMake( ( (col * self.itemSize.width) + (0.5f * self.itemSize.width) + horiOffset),
                                 ( ( (row * 0.75f) * self.itemSize.height) + (0.5f * self.itemSize.height) + vertOffset) );
return attributes;
}
```

This works like a charm. However, I wanted to add `UIKit` Dynamics to my app to make it more appealing and to create a better overall experience.
I followed a wonderful tutorial on objc.io called 'UICollectionView + UIKIT Dynamics'. According to the tutorial I have to change the method like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
return [self.dynamicAnimator layoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Doing so asks me to replace the code that computed the cells' centers.
I uploaded an image to clarify what it looks like. See the image above (my reputation is not high enough to post images, yet). I achieved the layout on the left (1) by adding the code from above to the following method in the `MyCollectionViewController`. However, as soon as I start scrolling, the layout changes back to layout (2) (with some ugly flickering, too). I guess that is because the dynamicAnimator is in control and uses the layoutAttributes that look more like layout (2).

The problem is that I do not know how I can tell the `dynamicAnimator` what the initial position of the cells is and that it should not use the standard FlowLayout centers.

The method in `MyCollectionViewController` that creates the right layout.. until the first scrolling action takes place:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSInteger row = (NSInteger) CGFloat_nearbyint( CGFloat_floor(indexPath.row / 2) ); // 2 = itemsPerRow
NSInteger col = indexPath.row % 2; // 2 = itemsPerRow
CGFloat horiOffset = ((row % 2) != 0) ? 0 : 60.f * 0.5f;
CGFloat vertOffset = 0;
 cell.center = CGPointMake( ( (col * 125.0f) + (0.5f * 125.0f) + horiOffset),
                                ( ( (row * 0.75f) * 125.0f) + (0.5f * 125.0f) + vertOffset) );

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
return cell;
}
```

After all, my question is how I can make layout (1) the permanent layout that is used at all times. Thus, how can I make the dynamicAnimator use layout (1) and not layout (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing makes no sense. Your code shows *two* implementations of `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`. That is nonsense. There can be only one.

Adding a dynamic animator to a collection view layout is a complex, subtle business — not something for a beginner.

- First, you have to appeal to the dynamic animator only during moments when you are, in fact, animating. There are certain times when you are animating and certain times when you are not. You have given no time or reason for animating, so it's utterly unclear what you want to animate and when.
- Second, you have to *meld* the information that comes from the layout and the information that comes from the animator, for just those items that are actually being animated.

You are not doing anything like that, so of course your results are weird.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that I should have given more information. I will do better next time. I edited my question and rewrote it completely. I kept the old version below for the sake of completeness.

Comment: That's good but it doesn't change my answer. There needs to be just one method and a switch that is thrown when animating, which in your case means when scrolling, and code that melds where the cells normally go with where the animator wants to put them.